# React Native - How to set state of variable contained in the imported js file

Tags: react-native, this, setstate

I have created a Loader.js to show ActivityIndicator in a Modal. I include Loader.js in my all pages and show it when page is processing / rendering.

Loader.js

```
const Loader = props => {
  const {
    loading,
    ...attributes
  } = props;

  return (
    <Modal
      transparent={true}
      animationType={'slide'}
      visible={ loading }
                   onRequestClose={() => { this.setState({loading: false})}}>
      <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
        <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
          <ActivityIndicator
            animating={loading} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default Loader;
```

In the screen where I am including Loader.js I have defined loading state variable and to show loader I do this.setState({loading: true});

And in render of the screen I have added:

```
      <Loader
          loading={this.state.loading} />
```

But sometimes the Loader hangs. I want to add a Close button in the Modal (Loader.js) to provide a way to the User to cancel Loader. But I am not able to set the state of loading to false inside Loader.js. I get error: _this.setState is not a function.

Please can anyone suggest how can I achieve closing the Loader? I do not want to modify the screens where Loader.js is being included as that would require changing multiple screens.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using Loader component in each screen, use it at root level. Single Loader for the app and manage the state via Context API.

Comment: You are using a functional component that is why setState is not working.Try to change it to a class component or use the newer hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple create a pure component like below :

**Loader.js**

```
import {ActivityIndicator, Modal, Text, View} from "react-native";
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';


class Loader extends PureComponent {

static propTypes = {
        onCancel: PropTypes.func,
        isLoading : PropTypes.bool
    };


    render() {
        return <Modal
            animated={true}
            visible={this.props.isLoading}
            transparent={true}
            animationType={'fade'}>

            <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}}>

                <View style={{
                    width: 120, height: 40, borderRadius: 5, padding: 10, backgroundColor: 'lightcoral',
                    justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'
                }}>

                    <ActivityIndicator
                        color='white'
                        size={'small'}
                        animating={true}/>

                    <Text style={{padding: 8, color: 'white'}}>Loading</Text>

                </View>

                <Button title={'Cancel'} onPress={this.props.onCancel}/>

            </View>

        </Modal>;
    }


}

export default Loader
```

Import that file and use loader in any `.js` using below command :

```
import Loader from "./source/Loader";
  <Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} onCancel={this._cancelProgress}/>
```

To manully handle cancel functionality you have to use callback function.

you have to define cancelProgress method in your .js file to change the state and pass it to `loader.js` file same as above example.

```
_cancelProgress = () => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false
        });
    }
```

Change the state of `isLoading` to true/false to show and hide the `ActivityIndicator`.

```
this.setState({isLoading: false})
```

Comment: Thats good. Thanks for sharing. But if the process hangs then I want to provide a way to User to Cancel the request. How can I achieve that? I was thinking to attach Cancel button in the Loader and in onPress call this.setState{(isLoading: false)}.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. But that means I have to change all the js files where I have included the Loader.

Comment: @Ashwanikumar yes .

Comment: The cancel works but I am getting a warning: Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onPress` is marked as required in `Button`, but its value is `undefined`. How can I get rid of this, please can you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: @Ashwanikumar you can define propType to avoid this error. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the same approach.
Here is my Loader.js :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Modal,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

class Loader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: this.props.isLoading
        }
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
        return {
          isLoading: nextProps.isLoading
        };
    }     

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType={'none'}
                visible={this.state.isLoading}
                style={{zIndex: 1100}}
                onRequestClose={() => { }}>
                <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
                    <View style={styles.activityIndicatorWrapper}>
                        <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.loading} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    modalBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        backgroundColor: '#00000040',
        zIndex: 1000
    },
    activityIndicatorWrapper: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        borderRadius: 10,
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    }
});

export default Loader
```

And use as below :

```js
<Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
```

It automatically close when you set `isLoading` false in your main component.